# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property --problem

Tags: java, hibernate, api

I am getting this error when I try to run my code in eclipse.

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: card_id of: om.gov.moh.dto.TreatmentMemberDTO

I tried different solutions. None of them helped to solve the issue

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
@Column(name = "MEMBERS_ID")
private Long members_id;

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
private String first_name;


@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "CARD_ID")
//@JsonIgnore //for ignore duplicate issue
@JsonBackReference
private TreatmentDueDTO treatment = new TreatmentDueDTO();

public TreatmentMemberDTO() {
    super();
}

public TreatmentMemberDTO(Long members_id, String first_name, String second_name, LocalDate dob) {
    super();
    this.members_id = members_id;
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.second_name = second_name;
    this.dob = dob;

}

public Long getMembers_id() {
    return members_id;
}

public void setMembers_id(Long members_id) {
    this.members_id = members_id;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;

public TreatmentDueDTO getTreatment() {
    return treatment;
}

public void setTreatment(TreatmentDueDTO treatment) {
    this.treatment = treatment;
}
```

}

The problem is in "card_id" join column.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please show the query you are trying to execute

Comment: You gave me a useful clue brother. The error was because of my query.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding card_id field/property in class TreatmentMemberDTO will help you